How I can solve flutter error on firebase_messagaing_web dependency?
I am getting this error when debugging flutter code. The error is related to firebase dependencies.  I need help in solving this error. The dependencies installed in pubsec.yamal is the following.
Find Error page here
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.16.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.4
  logger: ^1.1.0
  get: ^4.6.1
  email_validator: ^2.0.1
  intl: ^0.17.0
  table_calendar: ^3.0.1
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.6
  badges: ^2.0.1
  animate_do: ^2.0.0
  photo_view: ^0.12.0
  auto_size_text: ^3.0.0
  country_picker: ^2.0.9
  cached_network_image: ^3.3.0
  shimmer: ^2.0.0
  dio: ^4.0.0
  webview_flutter: ^2.0.13
  connectivity_plus: ^2.2.0
  video_player: ^2.2.13
  flutter_cached_pdfview: ^0.4.1
  bubble: ^1.2.1
  url_launcher: ^6.0.18
  device_info_plus: ^3.2.1
  wakelock: ^0.6.1+1
  jiffy: ^5.0.0
  readmore: ^2.1.0

  # FIREBASE
  firebase_auth: ^3.3.9
  cloud_firestore: ^3.1.10
  firebase_storage: ^10.2.9
  firebase_core: 1.24.0

  #  SLIDER
  card_swiper: ^1.0.4
  carousel_slider: ^4.0.0

  #  FILE PICKER
  file_picker: ^4.2.4
  open_file: ^3.2.1

  #  OTP TEXT FIELD
  otp_text_field: ^1.1.1

  #  INTRO SCREEN ON STARTING
  introduction_screen: ^3.0.0

  #  AGORA CALLING
  agora_rtc_engine: ^4.0.7
  avatar_glow: ^2.0.1
  just_audio:
  permission_handler: ^8.1.6

  #  NOTIFICATION
  firebase_messaging: ^11.2.8
  flutter_local_notifications: 8.1.1

  #  LOTTIE
  lottie: ^1.2.1

  #  RATTING
  flutter_rating_bar: ^4.0.0

  # page indicator:
  smooth_page_indicator: ^1.0.0+2

  # mobile ads:
  google_mobile_ads: ^1.3.0


I tried to update firebase packages to newer versions but still same error. I use command flutter pub upgrade to upgrade the dependencies.
